# Techniques for proving $M$ is totally unimodular.

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix $M$ what are the standard techniques for showing that $M$ is totally unimodular. I've already attempted to use the approach on wikipedia, but it will doesn't apply in my case. Are there other techniques for showing that a matrix is totally unimodular.

Comment: there is a theorem that says if you have two of {1,-1} in each column, and sum of each row goes to 0, then this matrix is TU